# Android Childactivity getParent question?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog, activitygroup

Basically I'm using ActivityGroup in my application. I have this situation:

I have Tabhost with activity A.

Activity A  creates childActivity B.

```
A  --->  B

startChildActivity("CollectionList", new Intent(this,MyCollectionList.class));
```

Activity B creates 3 childactivities C, D.

```
B  ---> C (childActivity of B)
startChildActivity("Recommended", new Intent(MyCollectionList.this,Recommended.class));


B  ---> D (childActivity of B)
startChildActivity("ExpectSoon", new Intent(MyCollectionList.this,ExpectSoon.class));
```

B creates another childActivity too, name it E.

```
B  ---> E
Intent previewMessage = new Intent(getParent(), MyCollectionId.class);
TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
parentActivity.startChildActivity("MyCollectionId", previewMessage);
```

So basically Activity C and D can start activity E too, with :

```
            Intent previewMessage = new Intent(getParent(), MyCollectionId.class);
            TabGroupActivity parentActivity = (TabGroupActivity)getParent();
            parentActivity.startChildActivity("MyCollectionId", previewMessage);
```

I had Override the onBackPressed method so I can control the back button.It looks like this :

```
    private ArrayList<String> mIdList;

@Override
  public void  onBackPressed  () {
      int length = mIdList.size();
      if ( length >=1) {
          Activity current = getLocalActivityManager().getActivity(mIdList.get(length-1));
          current.finish();
      }
  }
```

So my problem is  that when I'm in activity E and press the back button my application close.And the other problem that I have is with the alert dialog in activity E.

```
Button deactivate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deactivate);
        deactivate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder( getParent() )
                .setTitle( "Warning" )
                .setMessage( "The collection will be removed completely from the device.You can reactivate it later again.This operation requires internet connection." )
                .setPositiveButton( "Go ahead", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("AlertDialog", "Positive");
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton( "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("AlertDialog","Negative");
                    }
                })
                .show();    

            }

    });
```

When I start Activity E from A, when I click the button,which will show the alert dialog,everything is ok.But when I start activity E from C or D it throws me that exception :

```
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440): android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.app.LocalActivityManager$LocalActivityRecord@4630ea20 is not valid; is your activity running?
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.view.ViewRoot.setView(ViewRoot.java:509)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:177)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.show(AlertDialog.java:802)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at com.stampii.stampii.mystampii.MyCollectionId$4.onClick(MyCollectionId.java:75)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-15 15:48:22.819: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(32440):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**EDIT:**

My startChildActivity looks like this :

```
public void startChildActivity(String Id, Intent intent) {     
      Window window = getLocalActivityManager().startActivity(Id,intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP));
      if (window != null) {
          mIdList.add(Id);
          setContentView(window.getDecorView()); 
      }
```

}

latest LogCat,while using Recommended.parentActivity in ActivityE :

```
        new AlertDialog.Builder( Recommended.parentActivity )


08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967): java.lang.NullPointerException
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams.<init>(AlertController.java:743)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.AlertDialog$Builder.<init>(AlertDialog.java:273)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.stampii.stampii.mystampii.MyCollectionId$4.onClick(MyCollectionId.java:62)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:2408)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:8817)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:144)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4937)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
08-15 16:33:53.509: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(1967):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you  can do onething 
in ActivityA.java

```
public static Activity parentActivity;

onCreate()
{
     parentActivity=this;
} 
// start your child activity ie(E)
```

ActivityE.java

```
Button deactivate = (Button) findViewById(R.id.deactivate);
        deactivate.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                new AlertDialog.Builder( ActivityA.parentActivity.this )
                .setTitle( "Warning" )
                .setMessage( "The collection will be removed completely from the device.You can reactivate it later again.This operation requires internet connection." )
                .setPositiveButton( "Go ahead", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("AlertDialog", "Positive");
                    }
                })
                .setNegativeButton( "Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        Log.d("AlertDialog","Negative");
                    }
                })
                .show();    

            }

    });
```

Comment: Error : ActivityB.parentActivity cannot be resolved to a type.

Comment: you had not done the proper assignment check your B activity class name, and make sure you had taken activity as static ie(parentActitvity)

Comment: I used public static Activity parentActivity in class E(before onCreate()). In onCreate i put parentActivity=this;  and in alertdialog's code I did : new AlertDialog.Builder( Recommended.parentActivity.this )  (ActivityB=Recommended) and it's showing me an error.

Comment: in ActivityB, declare the parentActivity not in E, in E no need to declare anything except only  AlertDialog.Builder( ActivityB.parentActivity.this )

Comment: Still throwin the same exception,and showing an error when trying to add Recommended.parentActivity.this

Comment: are you calling activity E from B?

Comment: Yes, ActivityB is Recommended.class and ActivityE is MyCollectionId. I'm calling it like this :                startChildActivity("MyCollectionId", new Intent(Recommended.this,MyCollectionId.class)); from Recommended.class

Comment: I just edit my question with my startChildActivity method,which I forgot to include.Thanks for help!

Comment: ok can try the same with ActivityA what we done in ActivityB and In E pass ActivityA.parentActivity.this

Comment: This time it works but without this.Only ActivityA.parentActivity. Thanks really for the help!!!