# getResources / OpenRawSource causing runtime exception

Tags: android, android-context

I want to read from a text file. In a Java app, this

```
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));
```

works, in Android I tried

```
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader(getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.autobahnnetz_gps))) ;
```

which crashes the app. If I use this in the main activity class, it works fine. So I guess I have to pass the context to getResources by

```
getApplicationContext().getResources
```

but that doesnt work either.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Hrmmm... do you have any logcat output or any exception messages coming out? Can you post the class where you are using this code?

Comment: This is the class:http://pastebin.com/KirDVRSe

Comment: This is the class:http://pastebin.com/KirDVRSe

The Logcat doesnt give any errors, this is all I got: 
ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread$ActivityClientRecord, Intent) line: 1816 


e NullPointerException  (id=830007996248) 
 cause NullPointerException  (id=830007996248) 
 detailMessage null 
 stackState  (id=830007996280) 
 stackTrace null

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ya this problem is exist, but i am able to find one work around see **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7065108/android-childactivity-getparent-question/7065214#7065214)**

Comment: Can't really see how this helps, sorry.

Comment: i mean that take static Activity variable (Named actVar) and onCreate() assign it act=this; now when want to use context write this yourActivity.actVar.this instead of getApplicationContext()